# Can coconut cream be made from coconut flour?

Tags: cream, coconut

I have never seen or tried coconut cream (nor milk) personally, so I have no idea what should be it, but since I need it as a ingredient in my cocktails, I decided to give it a shot and try to make it.

I read on a [website](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coconut_cream#cite_note-0) that coconut cream is basically what separates on top of prepared coconut milk. Being unable to get my hands on a coconut, I have tried alternative technique (that did sound plausible to me): to boil coconut flour in a pot with enough water to cover it all, and then to strain it using cheesecloth.

What I got is a liquid that is mostly water, with slight taste of coconut, and it appears that nothing is going to separate on top of that liquid.

Is there something wrong with my alternative technique, or is that coconut flour can't even remotely replace freshly shredded coconut?

Any other thoughts?

Comment: I've edited the title to what I think more accurately describes the question; let me know if I've missed the mark.

Comment: Where are you from? Coconut milk is usually sold in non-perishable packs or cans so even if the local grocers don't have it you should be able to order it over mail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Coconut flour is what remains[<sup>1</sup>](http://www.gourmetsleuth.com/Dictionary/C/Coconut-flour-6716.aspx) when extracting the milk from coconut. So I doubt you can make anything resembling coconut milk (much less coconut cream) from it, unless the manufacturer has done an exceptionally poor job of doing so already!

Comment: That's what I have figured out in the meanwhile, by reading about process of getting coconut flour. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is little to no fat in coconut flour. Cream is largely fats. You're not going to get coconut cream by adding water.

You probably could, however, make something delicious by mixing coconut flour with 35% cream and then proceeding with a cream-based recipe.

Comment: Thanks for the tip of mixing the two. Will try it sometime, when I get my hands on real coconut cream! :)

Comment: No no. I meant add the coconut flour to regular cream, from cows.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. I've made both coconut and almond milk using flour. I got [the recipe from She Calls Me Hobbit](https://shecallsmehobbit.wordpress.com/2018/06/05/make-your-own-almond-and-coconut-milk-the-easy-way/), which says to use coconut flour, water, and xanthan gum to make coconut milk, and to add coconut oil to make coconut cream instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to mix the coconut flour with coconut oil? Mix thoroughly, then let sit in an enclosed jar for later use in recipes. I hope this was helpful.

Comment: I have NOT tried this, but based on first principles, it's worth a try. As noted above, coconut cream is (like dairy cream) the fatty part ... but skimmed or otherwise lightly processed. Coconut flour as little or no fat. Mix the flour with coconut oil (pure fat) and the combination may suffice as a non-dairy option for recipes that call for coconut cream.